# Backing Up Synced Folder

Tags: backup, sync

I manage accounts server. I have to backup everything. I deployed a software that copies the data from specified locations multiple times a day, and pastes it into onedrive folder. Now since it is a public server, I have a basic fear for ransomware. If something encrypts all my files, so it will be synced to the cloud and i am with no backup? I couldn't find much articles about what should I do in this situation?

Comment: You can backup the synced data to another device (e.g. external hard drive) and then take that device offline once that sync is complete. This gives you an offline and detached backup from the system you fear ransomware. The risk is the data that can be lost in a ransomware attack from the last offsite backup. There are other things you can do to protect yourself from ransomware too than just backups which involves educating yourself, locking down your system(s), and educating your users as well. Do some research on that as well.

Comment: Veeam Free Agent. Excellent (commercial) product. Disclaimer: just a happy user

Comment: yeah, if data on your computer gets corrupted with ransomware, the synchronisation can transmit that ransomware to your files in the cloud. So you could consider to backup your data to external disk with file history or others tool manually and regularly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a paid solution, then make sure it's a history-aware solution. If you are attacked, then you can return to the last backup before failure.

Maintain multiple backups in multiple locations. One on-site, one off-site & one cloud-based is a sensible minimum structure.

Mission-critical data needs mission-critical backups.